# Problems with .maps and import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got a problem with Angular 4 and `rxjs/add/operator/map`. Although I import `rxjs/add/operator/map` into my file, I can't use `.map`. Visual Basics always shows two messages:

> message: 'Declaration or statement expected.'
>
> message: 'Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?'

I have tried some things people advised on here and on the internet like:
'

```
npm install rxjs@latest --save
```

I have also tried to update everything with

```
npm update
```

But this problem does not want to go away.

Here is the context for my code. I'm very new to programming and this is a part of a tutorial:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(public http:Http) { 
    console.log('Data service connected...');
  }

  getPosts(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to import `map`.  Pretty sure the problem is the semicolon at the end of the first line of `getPosts()`.

Comment: The current accepted solution isn't correct, the semicolon isn't the problem, it was the syntax. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is semicolon after this.http.get method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(public http:Http) { 
    console.log('Data service connected...');
  }

 getPosts(){
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') 
    .map(res => res.json());
 }

}
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you very much.

Comment: Getting the same error and almost the same code. But this does not fix my issue

Comment: @RoarG raise new question and post link here...
answer to above mention question was just to correct syntax error...

Comment: @RoarG `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` does?

Answer (score 3):

Now that `RxJS` has been updated from `v5.x` to `v6.x`, we need to convert to pipe syntax:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

**THE FIX**:

Change your `map` import to:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Use the `.pipe(map( ... ))` approach.

**YOUR NEW SOLUTION**:

Taking your example, Here's how we can make it work with the newer syntax:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(public http:Http) { 
        console.log('Data service connected...');
    }

    getPosts(){
        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems with angular version 6rc there is a problem with that.
Checkout the [bug report and fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10058).

Actually what solved my issue was:

`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`

Answer (score 0):

I still had the .map error after I did the following:

npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

The fix that I used in addition to the install was to import rxjs/Rx:
import 'rxjs/Rx';

I hope this helped someone with this pain of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 9.1 now,
in xxx.service.ts

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class CustomerService {
  // inject HttpClient as dependency
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCustomers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/customers').pipe(map(res => res));
  }
}
```

in xxxx.component.ts

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
  customers;
  // inject dependency in constructor
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // calling service, subscribe() is to send request to server https://angular.io/guide/http
    this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => {
      this.customers = customers;
    });
  }
}
```

reference https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map